# What is the problem this code gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.0 and gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1

Tags: npm, error-handling, module, node-modules, node-gyp

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

I can't npm package install and uninstall in my projects. How can I solve it. Please help me. Thanks

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: